# Semantics - creating grammar in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, semantics, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to expand NLTK's [simple-sem.fcfg](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_teach/blob/master/examples/grammars/book_grammars/simple-sem.fcfg) so that it supports coordination of phrases. I want it to successfully parse a sentence like: Irene walks and Angus barks. Since this is represented as walk(Irene) & bark(Angus), I think the best way to achieve this is by adding a rule S -> S and S. What I can't grasp is how to do this with the semantic features... I've done this so far:

Added this rule:

```
S[SEM = <?subj(?vp)>] -> S[SEM = <?subj(?vp)>] <&> S[SEM = <?subj(?vp)>]
```

This doesn't work, so is there anyone who has some advice/links etc?

Comment: This is about the workings of the NLTK's semantics module, so I don't think it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no subject or VP in the relevant structure. Try writing a rule for `and` when used to conjoin sentences. What is it? *Sentence1 and Sentence2* gets the interpretation

```
<Sentence1> & <Sentence2>
```

I.e., take the meanings of the two sentences and conjoin them with `&`. In the notation of this library, it would be something like this:

```
S[SEM=<?p & ?q>] -> S[SEM=?p] 'and' S[SEM=?q]
```

I don't use this module and I can't test the example, so you might have to tweak the syntax. But I hope you get the idea.

PS. This kind of semantics usually assumes binary trees, so the interpretation would go in two steps like this:

```
S1 (and S2)
```

This means that you would interpret `and` as something that takes a sentence (i.e., S2) and gives you a conjunction function, which will combine with another sentence. But since the examples you link to include a three-place expansion (for VP), it doesn't seem to be necessary.

As for further reading (since you ask for "links"), I would recommend a simple introduction to formal semantics for natural language; e.g., the book by Heim and Kratzer.

Comment: @alexis...what is the meaning of (?p),(?q)...actually what is indicating by this sign(?).. ??? thanks .

Comment: They're placeholders matching the corresponding part in the expansion of the rule. Or "variables over feature values", as the nltk book puts it. See [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch09.html#using-attributes-and-constraints).